# php script displays nothing in browser, inspect elements shows <!--?php echo 'Some text'; ?-->

Tags: php

php script displays nothing in browser, inspect elements shows `<!--?php echo 'Text here I can't see'; ?-->`

This is my code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Something texttexttext</h1>

            <?php
    echo 'Text here I can't see';   
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open this in browser, I just get-"Something texttexttext" and not "Text here I can't see".

Comment: You need to switch on error reporting to see, that you have an error in your syntax.

Comment: If you view source of the rendered page in your browser, do you see the PHP code? If so, PHP engine may not be processing the file.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your echo statement closes prematurely with the `'` in `can't`. Try:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Something texttexttext</h1>

            <?php
    echo "Text here I can't see";   
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did, it's not it. My text was just "texttexttext", there was no "can't" in it. Thanks for help, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a quote inside your string and this is terminating your string prematurely, simply escape it with a backslash

```
    echo 'Text here I can\'t see';
```

Or just your quote to double quote

```
    echo "Text here I can't see";
```

Comment: It's not it. My text was just "texttexttext", there was no "can't" in it. Thanks for help, anyway

Comment: @Sanja It was in your code and it was not printed because of the error, please try to change what i told you and run the script, you will see `Text here I can't see`

Comment: We do not have ' in our language, my text was not "Text here I can't see" it was "Ovde cemo da naucimo PHP". So it wasn't it. I wrote this text, without thinking, so everyone could understand it.

Comment: @sanja are you sure php is enabled on your server/machine?

Comment: Oh, stupid mistake, I didn't write localhost in my browser. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Sanja it's ok, don't forget to accept and upvote answer to help people in the future with similar problems

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running this code in a html file not in a php file

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this from your local server (ie: your computer) or offline, I believe you need a server that supports php. Downloading xampp which includes an apache server would do the trick. Download it here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new file, called `phpinfo.php` and type this in:

```
 <?php
   phpinfo();
  ?>
```

If nothing shows up, your server is not running php (maybe only asp) or your trying to access the file locally in the browser. Remember php files need to be ran through a server, unlike HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

echo "Text here I can"'t'" see"; 
try it

Comment: Provide elaborative answers.

Answer (score -2):

First thing I notice is that you use three ' in the echo, that won't work. Try

```
<?php
    echo "Text here I can't see";   
        ?>
```